# How to extract text between <a class..> Text</a> + then order the text in a column

Tags: web-scraping, text, extract

I need help to remove html codes `< a >` and `< /a >` elements, and only have left the text between (marked in yellow in the picture.

The text should be listed in a table within a column with title "Description".

[Result from python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUgKi.png)

Code Im using to get the result:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup( html, 'html.parser' )
ul = soup.select("h2 > a" )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about print ([i.string for i in ul])

Answer (score 0):

Refer this to extract text between tags [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents)

or else 
try this one

```py
soup.p.next_sibling.strip()
```

1. you grab the <p> directly with `soup.p` *(this hinges on it being the first <p> in the parse tree)
2. then use `next_sibling` on the tag object that `soup.p` returns since the desired text is nested at the same level of the parse tree as the <p>
3. `.strip()` is just a Python str method to remove leading and trailing whitespace

in the interpreter this looks something like:

```
In [4]: soup.p
Out[4]: <p>tag contains</p>

In [5]: type(soup.p)
Out[5]: bs4.element.Tag

In [6]: soup.p.next_sibling
Out[6]: u'\n      Text inside in your tag \n      '

In [7]: type(soup.p.next_sibling)
Out[7]: bs4.element.NavigableString

In [8]: soup.p.next_sibling.strip()
Out[8]: u'Text inside in your tag'

In [9]: type(soup.p.next_sibling.strip())
Out[9]: unicode
```